# Invert the softmax function

Tags: probability, exponential-function, machine-learning, logistic-regression

Is it possible to revert the softmax function in order to obtain the original values $x_i$?

$$S_i=\frac{e^{x_i}}{\sum e^{x_i}} $$

In case of 3 input variables this problem boils down to finding $a$, $b$, $c$ given $x$, $y$ and $z$:

\begin{cases}
\frac{a}{a+b+c} &= x \\
\frac{b}{a+b+c} &= y \\
\frac{c}{a+b+c} &= z
\end{cases}

Is this problem solvable?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Note that in your three equations you must have $x+y+z=1$.
The general solution to your three equations are $a=kx$, $b=ky$, and $c=kz$ where $k$ is any scalar.

So if you want to recover $x_i$ from $S_i$, you would note $\sum_i S_i = 1$ which gives the solution $x_i = \log (S_i) + c$ for all $i$, for some constant $c$.

Comment: So it’s solvable up to a constant. Thank you!

Comment: Which ```c``` constant should I use? There is any way of calculating it?

Comment: @JoelCarneiro Any $c$ will work; the solution is not unique.

Comment: Any $c$ will work, one choice is if you augment the $x_i$ vector like $(0, x_1,...,x_n)$ then this will induce a particular $c$, note the corresponding log-sum-exp -- the gradient of which is the softmax -- would also be convex (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LogSumExp).

Comment: In the case anybody like me spend too much time figuring out $c$: If you know your 3 input variables have to sum to 1 then your $c = (1 - log(x \cdot y \cdot z))/3)$.

Comment: Usually they normalize the xi to sum to zero, in which case the inverse softmax would be log(x)-mean(log(x)). Or they code the first xi to be zero, in which case the inverse softmax would be log(x)-log(x[[1]]).

Answer (score 17):

The softmax function is defined as:

$$S_i = \frac{\exp(x_i)}{\sum_{j} \exp(x_j)}$$

Taking the natural logarithm of both sides:

$$\ln(S_i) = x_i - \ln(\sum_{j} \exp(x_j))$$

Rearranging the equation:

$$x_i = \ln(S_i) + \ln(\sum_{j} \exp(x_j))$$

The second term on the right-hand side is a constant over all $i$ and can be written as $C$. Therefore, we can write:

$$x_i = \ln(S_i) + C$$

This answer is adapted from [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/3uqgzj/question_regarding_inversion_of_softmax_function/) post on Reddit.

Comment: better use j in the summation

Comment: Not quite right. There is no subscript `i` on the `C` because `C` is a sum over all `i`s. Thanks for laying this out!